# Pass xml as a parameter to a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I am trying to pass an XML parameter from C# code to a stored procedure in SQL Server but it doesn't work.

```
public static void SaveReceiptTrans(string pSiteCode, string xml)
{
        try
        {
            string DBKey = "sn";
            string ConnStr = Encryption.DecryptString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[DBKey].ConnectionString);
            string CmdStr = "prc_pt_Fac_iu";

            SqlParameter[] SqlParams = new SqlParameter[1];

            SqlParams[0]            = new SqlParameter("@pReceiptsWithFactoryNameCode", SqlDbType.Xml);
            SqlParams[0].Direction  = ParameterDirection.Input;
            SqlParams[0].Value      = xml;

            int i = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnStr, CommandType.StoredProcedure, CmdStr, SqlParams);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UtilLogging.LogException(ex, "Error From -> ", pSiteCode);
        }
    }
```

But no operations are done on tables through stored procedure as if there is no call made to the stored procedure. I have tested the stored procedure with dummy xml string and it works fine but when pass the parameter from c# code it doesn't work.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc_pt_Fac_iu]
(
    @pReceiptsWithFactoryNameCode XML
)
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   BEGIN TRY    
      DECLARE @MAXTRANSID INT, @MAXMOVEID INT, @ROWCOUNT INT, @NEXTTRANSID INT, @NEXTMOVEID INT
      DECLARE @IDOC INT
      DECLARE @TEMPCOUNT INT, @INTFLAG INT

      SELECT 
         IDENTITY(INT) AS id, 
         line.item.value('@site_cde', 'char(8)') AS site_cde,  
         line.item.value('@po_nbr', 'char(17)') AS po_nbr,  
         line.item.value('@po_line_nbr', 'smallint') AS po_line_nbr, 
         line.item.value('@ran', 'int') AS ran, 
         line.item.value('@factory_name_code', 'int') AS factory_name_code, 
         NULL AS item_id, 
         NULL AS qty,
         NULL AS cur_loc_id,
         NULL AS cur_loc_status,
         NULL AS trans_id,
         NULL AS [user_id]
      INTO 
         #tmpReceiptsWithFactoryNameCode  
      FROM 
         @pReceiptsWithFactoryNameCode.nodes('/POLines/POLine') AS line(item) 

      SELECT  
         @MAXTRANSID = COALESCE(MAX(trans_id),0)
      FROM 
         PartsTrack_Receipt_Trans (NOLOCK) 
      WHERE 
         trans_id IS NOT NULL

      UPDATE rt 
      SET trans_id = @MAXTRANSID + temp.id,
          factory_name_code = temp.factory_name_code
      FROM PartsTrack_Receipt_Trans_BKP rt 
      INNER JOIN #tmpReceiptsWithFactoryNameCode temp ON rt.receipt_ack_nbr = temp.ran 
                                                      AND rt.po_nbr = temp.po_nbr 
                                                      AND rt.po_line_nbr = temp.po_line_nbr
END

public static int ExecuteNonQuery(string pConnectionString, CommandType pCommandType, string pCommandText, SqlParameter[] pSqlParameters)
{
        SqlConnection lSqlConnection = null;

        try
        {
            lSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(pConnectionString);

            SqlCommand lSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
            lSqlCommand.CommandType = pCommandType;
            lSqlCommand.Connection = lSqlConnection;
            lSqlCommand.CommandText = pCommandText;
            lSqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 180;

            if (pSqlParameters != null)
            {
                foreach (SqlParameter lSqlParameter in pSqlParameters)
                    lSqlCommand.Parameters.Add(lSqlParameter);
            }

            lSqlConnection.Open();

            return lSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlExp)
        {
            throw sqlExp;
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw exp;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (lSqlConnection != null && lSqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                lSqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

I searched and found that this is the correct way to pass the xml parameter.

Then what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDITED:

I found the issue. All the suggested methods were right but since xml is case sensitive I found the mis-match in xml node i was passing.

Comment: What happens when you debug? Any exceptions?

Comment: no exception, it passes the ExecuteNonQuery with a return value of -1. I wonder if this is the way to pass xml to stored proc.

Comment: What's the value of the XML string that actually gets passed through your C# code? Is there an issue if you directly pass that to the SP?

Comment: <POLines>
 <POLine po_nbr="4200081264" po_line_nbr="10" ran="1054713" factory_name_code="19" />
</POLines>......................There is no issue when i pass it directly to SP. It works. Problem is with when i pass it from code, nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm, could you please also edit your question to add the definition of `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery is a generic function in my project. I have edited the question with its code.

Comment: have you tried changing the sqlparameter type to SqlDbType.varchar instead of SqlDbType.Xml? I think maybe SqlDbType.Xml expects xml to be passed in some other way and not in a string.

Comment: Could you please remove the answer from you EDITED section, and post it as the accepted answer to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass XML value [with SqlXml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34e4kcbw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Then it should work.

Comment: tried this also like this - SqlParams[0].Value = new SqlXml(new XmlTextReader(xmlDocument.InnerXml, XmlNodeType.Document, null));  But not working

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the variable `xml` as an instance of `SqlXml` class. You can do this as shown below:

```
SqlParams[0].Value = new SqlXml(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)));
```

Comment: I think i am passing the data as xml attributes instead of elements. Could that be a reason?

Comment: But you said the string you get works when you directly pass it right?